# How to use tracking id of google analytics in android app?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to integrate google analytics with my android app. I followed the steps in the following link:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/#manifest

Then i tried the look at the statistic of my app, but it seems like analytics is not working, i must have done something wrong. The problem is, in those steps we do not make use of the tracking id, and in google analytic's web site, it says that

```
Download the Google Analytics SDK for Android or iOS and implement the tracking code,
including this tracking ID.
```

What does it mean to "implement the tracking id"? What should i do about this can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Did you replace your Tracking ID in `<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXX-Y</string>`

Comment: @SunilMishra no, i did not do that. Where should i do it?

Comment: oh i see where it is, thanks i will try it now

Comment: That is the 3 point of the tutorial you are referring to.

Comment: @SunilMishra id did that step, thanks. Should i wait for some time to look at the statistics, or do they immediately appear on the google analytics web site?

Comment: They don't appear immediately, you can wait for 12/24 hours and then you can check it

Comment: @panpa once you integrate google analytics with android app, the detailed statistics will take some time to start appearing, but the real time data will start appearing soon. So you should always check the real time tab to see any hits and thereby to verify whether your integration is correct

Comment: thank you all for the answers i made it work now

Comment: AFAIK the Android realtime data doesn't start immediately. I think the data is agrgegated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).getTracker(ga_trakingId);
```

Then you can **SET** some variables, that will be send to GoogleAnalytics:

```
tracker.set(Fields.APP_NAME, "Best Android Application");
tracker.set(Fields.APP_VERSION, "1.0");
```

To **SEND** some info, events:

```
tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("UX", "App Launch", null, null).build());
```

You must watch [Behind the Code: The Google Analytics v3 Mobile SDKs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMRAHDdLYWo), all info from there.

**Update 1**

Google Analytics API v4 you should create google-services.json file from [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) and then you can use:

```
public Tracker getTracker() {
    return GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
}
```

And then you canuse  it like this way:

```
getTracker().setScreenName("SomeScreenOrActivityName");
getTracker().send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build()); // send screen name
```

Comment: could u please provide me the getTracker method?

Comment: @Sangeetha I'm make update of answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

The new process generates a file by Google which is called *GoogleService-Info.plist*.

This file contains (key, string) and one of them is:

```
<key>TRACKING_ID</key>
<string>*YOUR TRACKING ID*</string> // Auto generated by GAI
```

Just open the file and confirm that this is your tracking ID.